# bootstrap alert fade class does not display

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I have this code in http://plnkr.co/edit/b0kp65zZoAn12D1LrotZ.

Why, if I add the `fade` class, won’t the text display? I just want to show an alert message and fade after a time. Any idea what’s wrong with this code?

```
<div class="alert fade" bs-alert><strong>Hey!</strong> This is a static alert.</div>
```

Comment: Please don't just link to a site with code on it.  Include the code in your question and any error messages you are seeing (if any) in the developer tools of your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the `in` class.

```
<div class="alert fade in" bs-alert><strong>Hey!</strong> This is a static alert.</div>
```

Comment: the text display but it will not fade away. Any idea how to fade it away?

Comment: $(".alert").alert('close');